# Hide composite control in parent with FillLayout

Tags: java, swt

I have a composite with a `FillLayout`

```
comp.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
```

I created 2 composites inside this one.

Now I want to hide the first one and to free the occupied place.

```
child1.setVisible(false);
```

I know there is way to exclude a composite if `GridData` and `GridLayout` is used but I am using a `FillLayout`.

What can be done?

Comment: Is `disposing` the widget an option?

Comment: The I'm afraid I don't know any solution without using `GridLayout` and `GridData` or some nifty `moveAbove()` and `layout()` action...

Answer (score 0):

A hack would be to `Control.setParent()` and add it to a Shell that is not visible. Be aware that `Control.setParent()` may not be supported on all platforms. IMHO such a hack to avoid using `GridLayout` is not worth it and you should just replace the `FillLayout` with `GridLayout`.